# Factory_girl validation problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I use factory_girl for generating users and database_cleaner to clean up database after tests, but I have validation errors: uniqueness. Here is my spec_helper, user model and other files that affect.

https://gist.github.com/2006719

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like User is not generated dynamically every time page is generated. Try changing line 12 in factories to:

```
f.user_id { Factory(:user).id }
```

or even

```
f.user { Factory :user }
```

Hope, it helps.